# Creating a sequence to database in java code dynamically

Tags: java, postgresql, sequence, seam

I am using seam and postgresql and I am trying to create sequences dynamically to database in my java code. I tried to use this code but it didn't let me to do that.

```
String sequenceName = "doc.correspondence_documentno_" + year;
getEntityManager()
    .createNativeQuery(
        "CREATE SEQUENCE "
            + sequenceName
            + " INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1 CACHE 1").executeUpdate();
```

I cant create the sequence directly to postgresql becouse its name needs to be created dynamically (sequenceName).

I also tried to use namedQuery but it also didnt work.

Comment: What's the issue? Do you get an error message?

Comment: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query

Comment: Just a guess: is there some kind of alternative to `executeUpdate()` which would allow to execute *raw* SQL?